# Нет подключения к wifi

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, wifi, micropython

Всем привет, на базе `nodemcu v3` и `micropython`, решил сделать серверную часть(которая у меня на ПК) и клиентскую часть(которая на `nodemcu`). Вся проблема в том, что клиент исправно подключается к сети, но выводит ошибку, которая будет представлена после кода клиента.
Код клиента-

```
import time
import os
from socket import *

print(os.listdir())
import network

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF) # create station interface
ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
wlan.active(True)       # activate the interface
wlan.connect('Stalker', '5451286101abxc') # connect to an AP
print(wlan.scan())
print(wlan.isconnected())
print(wlan.active())
print(ap_if.active())
print(wlan.ifconfig())




print("\n"+"ds")
"""while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ("192.168.0.105", 23456)

    sock.connect(server_address)


    sock.send(b"ds")

    # wait for two seconds
    time.sleep(2)

    # close connection
    sock.close()"""



s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # создаем аналогичный сокет, как у сервера
s.connect(("192.168.0.105", 25565)) # коннектимся с сервером
tm = s.recv(1024) # Принимаем не более 1024 байта данных
s.close() # закрываем соединение
```

Постоянно выводит ошибку -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED
```

Код сервера-

```
# load additional Python module
import socket

# create TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ("192.168.0.105", 25565)
sock.bind(server_address)

# listen for incoming connections (server mode) with one connection at a time
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # wait for a connection
    print ('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        # show who connected to us
        print ('connection from', client_address)

        # receive the data in small chunks and print it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(64)
            if data:
                # output received data
                print ("Data: %s" % data)
            else:
                # no more data -- quit the loop
                print ("no more data.")
                break
    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Что делать, я не понимаю, всем заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Биндер на 0.0.0.0 сделай

Comment: Для чего мне биндер на 0.0.0.0, если у меня сервак на другом компе находится?

Comment: именно поэтому)